# switching views with modalViewControllers

Tags: iphone, xcode

I'm making an app that uses a lot of views.  To navigate between them I'm using these two lines of code:

```
[self presentModalViewController:nameOfView animated:YES];    
[self.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

scattered in various parts of my code.  This works fine. However, I cannot open a view from a view that I opened using the presentModalController code.  For example, if I have a main view that opens up table view, I cannot open a detail view from the didSelectRowAtIndex method. (SIGABRT)

HELP!!

Comment: Can you show more code so it's easier to understand your question?

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a UINavigationController.  Read the documentation.  There are tons of tutorials on this as well